# The concept of defining of trigonometric functions of a real number

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone, please, help me with the concept of defining trigonometric functions?
I don't understand what is written here:

[image]

As far as I remember from school, the sine is the ratio of the opposite leg (of an angle in the right triangle) to hypotenuse. However, in the image above I don't see any right triangles. I don't even see any triangles at all! How is it then that "we define that sine of t is equal to y"?

I seem to be missing some important link here and, therefore, cannot grasp the basics of the concept of definition of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Useful google image search -- [trigonometry + unit + circle + triangle](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigonometry+unit+circle+triangle&tbm=isch)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - Bunch of images, but no explanations.

Comment: The answer is that we generalize: we start in a space where one principle holds but then consider a more general form of that principle that holds in a larger space encompassing the first. This approach is ubiquitous in math. We start from the set of right angled triangles with unit hypotenuse, defining $\sin()$, $\cos()$ as its side-lengths. But if we recognize that the hypotenuse can be treated as a unit radius in Quadrant I, we can keep it turning into the other quadrants, now treating $\sin()$, $\cos()$ as the location of its endpoint. This naturally generalizes the first definition.

Comment: @Joe - Only for cases in quadrant 1.

Comment: *Bunch of images, but no explanations.* --- Plenty of explanations if you click on the images and visit their various originating pages. Regarding the answer by @Joe in the linked question (nice, so +1), of course it's only for cases in quadrant 1 since the right triangle trig relations only correspond to quadrant 1 angles. Did you miss his analogy with defining exponents that are not positive integers?